# Need to move a debian server from i686 to x86_64 architecture

Tags: debian, ruby-on-rails, migration, 32bit-64bit

I have a `debian` server that I need to move from one hosting provider to another. I don't really know how the old server was setup, all I know is that it's running a `Ruby on Rails` application with a lot of custom libraries installed and that I should prepare myself for a painful migration.

**Old server:**
-os: `debian 5.0.9`
-used disk space: `3.2GB`
-architecture: `i686`

**New server:**
-os: `debian 5.0.9`
-free disk space: `10GB`
-architecture: `x86_64`

As you can see the problem is that the servers are running different architectures.

**Q: Is there anyway I could somehow migrate the old to the new server in a few steps (or am I just dreaming I could) ?**

I was thinking maybe I could:
-get list of packages and gems installed on old server and use for loop to install them all on the new
-copy the disk content from old to new  server while excluding what is architecture-specific (the problem is that I don't really know what to exclude).

Comment: I don't see how this would be a painful migration; it's a pretty standard thing for a sysadmin to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a step-by-step guide in the Debian Wiki to upgrade from 32 to 64 bit. http://wiki.debian.org/Migrate32To64Bit
This is really ugly plus you have the problem with your Ruby installation. Are you sure your Ruby libs are running with 64 bit?
I would do definitley do a full backup/image/whatever of the machine, so you can rollback to a functional state in case things go wrong.

Answer (score 4):

`dpkg --get-selections > /backup/installed-software.log` should dump everything installed to installed-software.log

`dpkg --set-selections < /backup/installed-software.log` then `dselect` should restore it.

You may also need to copy config files from /etc/ - this will depend on your specific set up.

you may also want to install [ia-32-libs](http://packages.debian.org/stable/ia32-libs) for supportng ia32 software on x86

Up until this point, you shouldn't have too many issues.

Now, debian does support running x86 libs on x64, so its a matter of copying over the files, looking at what breaks, and installing the appropriate libraries should do the trick

Alternately, a trickier, but 'simpler' option may be to [set up a 32 bit chroot](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=18001) in the system, then simply copy over the setup of the old server into the newer one. Another install guide [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/356)